# How to access Ethereum Transaction Trie using LevelDB

Tags: merkle-patricia-tries, leveldb

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72582211/how-to-access-ethereum-transaction-trie-using-leveldb][1]

I wanted to access Ethereum Transaction Trie using LevelDB, but it's working only for Block 0, for any other block it's not given me any data. Just wondering how does web3.eth.getTransaction() works internally: Here is the code:

```
const Trie1 = require ('merkle-patricia-tree').SecureTrie
const { Account, BN, bufferToHex, rlp } = require ('ethereumjs-util') ;
var levelup = require('levelup');
var leveldown = require('leveldown');
const gethDbPath = '/Users/AK/gethDataDir/geth/chaindata'
const db = new levelup(leveldown(gethDbPath))
async function test() {
    const txnRoot = '0x51736d42e0e8fe95c3e609e5e5fb70da476613d24b5cd0d710d68190649c39f4'
    const txnRootBuffer = Buffer.from(txnRoot.slice(2), 'hex')
    const trie1 = new Trie1(db,txnRootBuffer)
    const stream = trie1.createReadStream()
    stream.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`key: ${bufferToHex(data.key)}`)
        console.log(`Value: ${bufferToHex(rlp.decode(data.value))}`)
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log('1111--->>> Finished')
    })
  }
  test() ;
```

Comment: Below is the transaction I am trying to access the levelDB directly. I tried almost all combinations like TxnRoot, TxnHash, with or without Kecak256 etc

Comment: Below is the transaction I am trying to access the levelDB directly. I tried almost all combinations like TxnRoot, TxnHash, with or without Kecak256 etc

Comment: Im not even sure the transactions trie is kept after being assembled once to verify the block. If they are this is a big deal because an RPC method could be added. In the meantime I was doing it by rebuilding the entire block like this https://github.com/zmitton/eth-proof/blob/master/getProof.js#L17